# Wrong syntax typescript when I try to return mutiple type of interface in function

Tags: typescript

I have some code like below. Basically c is a function can return instance of A or B. But when I run this code below Its always show me the error

```
Property 'a' does not exist on type 'A | B'.
  Property 'a' does not exist on type 'B'.
```

Here is my code:

```
interface A {
  a: string;
}
interface B {
  b: string;
}

const c = (params: any): A | B => {
  return params
}

const x = c({a: 'a'})

console.log(x.a)
```

Any one can help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create an interface that extends both of the other interfaces and make the properties optional. So that way the compiler will correct interpret and expect both the types at compile time and also give you the freedom to either populate the properties of `A` or `B` depending on your needs.

```ts
interface A {
  a?: string;
}

interface B {
  b?: string;
}

interface Both extends A,B {}

const c = (params: Both): Both  => {
  return params
}

const x = c({a: 'a'})
console.log(x.a);
```

###### [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgfgC5kBnMKUAcwG4sBfLLUSWRFAIUx2QCMjTyVWgybho8JMnYB7MAAtkEAB6QQAExJoANJwwiE0kGWQJkAXmQAKAA5wocALYliM%20QEoXsheYB8XXFAQYACuUCDItvZO9IwGRmDISuYmlhhwxADkcBl0blhxJNIANhAAdEXSlJZKpXBu1EA)